# Airnotifier server 500 response JSON

Tags: android, python, json

I want to use [Airnotifier](https://airnotifier.github.io/) as a GCM server. The server is placed at my home right now. I forwarded the ports: 8000, 8801, 5228-5230 to the server. I know the server is working because I can connect to the web interface from another location. But now in the app I want to register a token so I'm using this code:

```
    String url = "http://URL:8801/api/v2/tokens";

    JSONObject json =new JSONObject();
    try {
        json.put("device", "android");
        json.put("token","tokennnn");
        json.put("chanel","default");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    BufferedReader br = null;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );


    try {
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("X-AN-APP-NAME", "appname");
        connection.setRequestProperty("X-AN-APP-KEY", "appkey");
        connection.setUseCaches( false );
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    OutputStreamWriter wr= null;
    try {
        wr = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String jsonMessage = json.toString();
    try {
        wr.write(jsonMessage);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String httpresponsecode = null;
    String httpresponsemessage = null;

    httpresponsecode = Integer.toString(connection.getResponseCode());
    httpresponsemessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

    Log.i(TAG, "JSON Message: " + jsonMessage);
    Log.i(TAG, "HTTP Response: " + httpresponsecode + ": " + httpresponsemessage);
```

I've tried multiple things but this is the outcome:

```
JSON Message: {"device":"android","token":"tokennnn","chanel":"default"}
HTTP Response: 500: Internal Server Error
```

And on the server I get this:

[The problem on the server (IMAGE)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBtfD.jpg)

I know there is some JSON problems decoding with python. But I cannot figure out the problem.

**EDIT**
Found the solution. See answer in the answer comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in a desperate last attempt. I was working on this for the entire day. Right now after asking it here I found the solution to the problem. Needed to close the OutputStreamWriter.....

```
    try {
        wr.write(jsonMessage);
        wr.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```